# How to SELECT parts from a comma-separated field with a LIKE statement

Tags: postgresql, select

I have a field in my database which could be filled with something like this:

```
  1,4,8,14,16
```

Now, I'd like to query that field with a LIKE parameter - or something similar. That is, I receive a parameter via a form, and I am looking for any row in that table which has in the above mentioned field that number.

That parameter could be for example "14". And then I can query

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field LIKE '14'
```

That works fine.

But if my value is "4", then I have a problem, because the result being returned will be "4" and "14". Using the comma as additional separator isn't useful either...

I guess this is either a flaw in (the very simple) database layout. Or I am just missing the simple approach to the query... Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Rather than fighting the symptoms you should fix the real problem: don't store values as comma separated lists. Read up on database normalization.

Comment: Even an array would have been better than csv... Normalization will fix your problem and is a best practice anyway.

Comment: Ok, got that. Demands more time for the developer at the beginning; but should be better over the long run. Thx for pointing this out!