# how to select data row from a comma separated value field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

My question is not exactly but  similar to this question

[How to SELECT parts from a comma-separated field with a LIKE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995509/how-to-select-parts-from-a-comma-separated-field-with-a-like-statement)

but i have not seen any answer there. So I am posting my question again.

i have the following table

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╗
║ VacancyId  ║  Media      ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║     1      ║ 32,26,30    ║
║     2      ║ 31, 25,20   ║
║     3      ║ 21,32,23    ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I want to select data who has media id=30 or media=21 or media= 40

So in this case the output will return the 1st and the third row.

How can I do that ?

I have tried media like '30' but that does not return any value. Plus i just dont need to search for one string in that field .

My database is SQL Server

Thank you

Comment: edit your question via adding expected output.

Comment: thanks for the response . I added the line for my expected output.

Comment: Did you Try using WHERE Media LIKE '%30%' OR Media LIKE '%21%' or OR Media LIKE '%40%'

Comment: Does your number of values to match are going to be stay same ?

Comment: Coder of Code: The values are going to be the same.

Comment: Ahmed - yes i have tried. . There is one limitation. If i write media like '%4%' it will selct all the rows 4, 14, 24, 34, 40, 41, 42 , 43, 44 etc

Answer (score 3):

It's never good to use the comma separated values to store in database if it is feasible try to make separate tables to store them as most probably this is `1:n` relationship.

If this is not feasible then there are following possible ways you can do this,
If your number of values to match are going to stay same, then you might want to do the series of `Like` statement along with `OR/AND` depending on your requirement.

Ex.-

```
WHERE
    Media LIKE '%21%'
    OR Media LIKE '%30%'
    OR Media LIKE '%40%'
```

However above query will likely to catch all the values which contains `21` so even if columns with values like `1210`,`210` will also be returned. To overcome this you can do following trick which is hamper the performance as it uses functions in `where` clause and that goes against making [Seargable](https://csharpcornerplus.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/how-to-optimize-sql-queries-and-make-them-sargable/) queries.
But here it goes,

```
--Declare valueSearch variable first to value to match for you can do this for multiple values using multiple variables.

Declare @valueSearch = '21'

-- Then do the matching in where clause
WHERE 
    (',' + RTRIM(Media) + ',') LIKE '%,' + @valueSearch + ',%'
```

If the number of values to match are going to change then you might want to look into [FullText Index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/) and you should thinking about the same.
And if you decide to go with this after `Fulltext Index` you can do as below to get what you want,

Ex.-

```
WHERE 
     CONTAINS(Media, '"21" OR "30" OR "40"')
```

Comment: Has the problem that when search for `'4'` you'll also match with `'3,49,69'`.  To resolve this the list itself should start and end with `','` and the search values should do the same...  `',3,48,69,' LIKE '%,4,%'`.  That said, you are right that the data structure is poor and "should" be normalised out.

Comment: @MatBailie just updated the answer. Missed it at first glance.

Comment: Same applies to `CONTAINS`

Answer (score 2):

The best possible way i can suggest is first you have do comma separated value to table using [This link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitjet/2009/12/11/convert-comma-separated-string-to-table-4-different-approaches/) and you will end up with table looks like below.

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Media in('30','28')
```

It will surely works.

Comment: The suggested structure is correct, that's how it should be modelled *(though I would also stipulate that the media field be an INT)*.  But the resulting query no longer needs to use LIKE...  `media IN (21,30,40)` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that any `Media` value containing the string `30` will be one you wish to return, you just need to include wildcards in your `LIKE` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Media LIKE '%30%'
```

Bear in mind though that this would also return a record with a Media value of `298,300,302` for example, so if this is problematic for you, you'll need to consider a more sophisticated method, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Media LIKE '%,30,%'
OR Media LIKE '30,%'
OR Media LIKE '%,30'
OR Media = '30'
```

If there might be spaces in the strings (as per in your question), you'll also want to strip these out:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE REPLACE(Media,' ','') LIKE '%,30,%'
OR REPLACE(Media,' ','') LIKE '30,%'
OR REPLACE(Media,' ','') LIKE '%,30'
OR REPLACE(Media,' ','') = '30'
```

**Edit**: I actually prefer [Coder of Code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643104/coder-of-code)'s solution to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ',' + LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(Media,' ',''))) + ',' LIKE '%,30,%'
```

You mention that would wish to search for multiple strings in this field, which is also possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Media LIKE '%30%'
   OR Media LIKE '%28%'

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Media LIKE '%30%'
  AND Media LIKE '%28%'
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. This works. But there is one limitation. If I write media like '%4%' then it will all the the row with  4 , 14, 24, 34, 44 . How to overcome that limit?

Comment: @Bashabi yes, I noted this in my answer. I will update now to show a way you can be more sophisticated and handle this better.

Comment: There is a 4th edge case; where the media field has only one value *(`'30'`)* with no leading or trailing `','`

Comment: @MatBailie yes, you're right, I will update for that. To be honest, I think [Coder of Code](http://stackoverflow.com/users/643104/coder-of-code)'s handling of this is better, just wrapping the whole value in a leading and trailing comma.

Comment: I think you'll find that was my suggestion in a comment as well as in an answer ;)

Comment: Indeed it was, apologies. I like **your** handling of this better. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, but the performance is inevitably poor.  You should, as others have said, normalise this structure.

```
WHERE
       ',' + media + ',' LIKE '%,21,%'
    OR ',' + media + ',' LIKE '%,30,%'
    Etc, etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree not a good idea comma seperated values stored like that. Bu if you have to;

I think using inline function is will give better performance;

```
Select VacancyId, Media from (
  Select 1 as VacancyId, '32,26,30' as Media
  union all 
  Select 2, '31,25,20'
  union all 
  Select 3, '21,32,23'
) asa
CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_StrToTable(Media, ',') tbl
where CAST(tbl.Result as int) in (30,21,40)
Group by VacancyId, Media
```

Output is;

```
VacancyId   Media
----------- ---------
1           32,26,30
3           21,32,23
```

and our inline function script is;

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[udf_StrToTable]') and xtype in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF'))
drop function [dbo].udf_StrToTable
GO

CREATE FUNCTION udf_StrToTable (@List NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter NVARCHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE
With Encryption
AS
RETURN 
(   WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST(endpos+1 as int), CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as inx, 
           SUBSTRING(@List,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@List)+1)-stpos) Result
    FROM Split
)
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a RECURSIVE CTE to identify the position of each comma within the string then uses SUBSTRING to return all strings between the commas.

I've left some unnecessary code in place to help you get you head round what it's doing. You can strip it down to provide exactly what you need.

```
DROP TABLE #TMP
CREATE TABLE #TMP(ID INT, Vals CHAR(100))

INSERT INTO  #TMP(ID,VALS)
VALUES
(1,'32,26,30')
,(2,'31, 25,20')
,(3,'21,32,23')

;WITH cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT
        ID
        ,VALS
        ,0 POS
        ,CHARINDEX(',',VALS,0) REM
    FROM
        #TMP
    UNION ALL
        SELECT ID,VALS,REM,CHARINDEX(',',VALS,REM+1)
        FROM
        cte c 
        WHERE CHARINDEX(',',VALS,REM+1) > 0
    UNION ALL
        SELECT ID,VALS,REM,LEN(VALS)
        FROM
        cte c 
        WHERE POS+1 < LEN(VALS) AND CHARINDEX(',',VALS,REM+1) = 0
    )
,cte_Clean
    AS
    (
    SELECT ID,CAST(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(VALS,POS+1,REM-POS))),',','') AS INT) AS VAL FROM cte
    WHERE POS <> REM
    )
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    cte_Clean
WHERE
    VAL = 32
ORDER BY ID
```