# need to take a single id from table where id is stored as multiple string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, where-clause

i have a table called product. The values in table is as follows(given one row as an example).

```
productid     name                   group_id          slug
222          testproduct           22,24,26,28        testproduct
```

and so on. for a search functionality am getting the module id as 24 i need to get the product details where group_id = 24;
my code is as follows

```
$idd = 24;
$products->where('group_id', $idd);
```

i didnt get the expected answer since the group_id is as multiple elements in the field. i need to get the product details of productid 222 where group_id is 24. How can i make the query for that.Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not SQL code.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972610/how-to-select-data-row-from-a-comma-separated-value-field

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use `find_in_set()` to search for a value in a CSV list:

```
where find_in_set(?, group_id)
```

The question mark represents the value to search for.

You should be able to adapt this piece of code so you can run it from your ORM.